# How to update record upon Re-assign in Approval Process ?

Tags: approval-process

I have been pulling my hair out on this one. There are a bunch of things I would like to do upon the re-assigning of an Approval Process but they require the editing of the parent record in order to kick off other actions/Apex.

I have even tried to write a trigger which would be initiated upon the creation of a new ProcessInstanceStep or ProcessInstanceWorkItem - but apparently we are not allowed to write triggers for those objects.

So does anybody have any kind of workaround for this ? I've done extensive research and am starting to think it truly is impossible. It really should be an out-of-box feature.

Comment: Can you please give more step by step details on this scenario?

Comment: During an approval process a user has the option of "Reassign" or "Approve/Reject". If a user chooses to Reassign then the approval process can then be approved/rejected by somebody different but no kind of modification is made to the actual main record, nor are you given the option to include such actions as a Field Update to the main record upon a Reassign. Therefore, it is impossible to use a trigger with this because there is no event to launch the trigger.

Comment: @Zoom_v:Did you find any solution for this ? Any ideas to proceed on this?